Cannot Bind PVC to Existing PV with GCS Fuse Enabled in Airflow on GKE
I’m deploying Apache Airflow on GKE, and while most of the setup works fine, I'm having trouble binding a PersistentVolumeClaim (PVC) to an existing PersistentVolume (PV) that uses GCS Fuse.
The PV is backed by a GCS bucket and works as expected when used with other pods created using a standard deployment and generated YAML files. However, when I try to use the same PV with Airflow, I encounter the following error:

MountVolume.SetUp failed for volume "gcs-fuse-csi-pv" : rpc error: code = FailedPrecondition desc = failed to find the sidecar container in Pod spec

It seems related to the GCS Fuse CSI driver setup.
Here’s what I’ve done so far:
The GCS Fuse CSI driver is installed and configured on the cluster.
The PV is correctly defined and points to the GCS bucket.
The PVC is trying to bind to the PV but fails with the above error.
Here is the tabular representation for csidrivers
| NAME                                  | ATTACHREQUIRED | PODINFOONMOUNT | STORAGECAPACITY | TOKENREQUESTS                       | REQUIRESREPUBLISH | MODES                | AGE  |
|---------------------------------------|----------------|----------------|-----------------|-------------------------------------|-------------------|----------------------|-------|
| filestore.csi.storage.gke.io          | false          | true           | false           | <unset>                             | false             | Persistent           | 4d5h |
| gcsfuse.csi.storage.gke.io            | false          | true           | false           | my-gcp-project-name.svc.id.goog     | true              | Persistent, Ephemeral| 4d5h |
| mtls.gke.io                           | true           | true           | false           | <unset>                             | true              | Ephemeral            | 4d5h |
| parallelstore.csi.storage.gke.io      | false          | true           | false           | <unset>                             | true              | Persistent           | 4d5h |
| pd.csi.storage.gke.io                 | true           | false          | false           | <unset>                             | false             | Persistent           | 4d5h |
| podcertificate.gke.io                 | true           | true           | false           | <unset>                             | true              | Ephemeral            | 4d5h |


And for the kubectl get pods -n kube-system | grep csi:
| POD NAME                            | READY | STATUS   | RESTARTS | AGE      |
|-------------------------------------|-------|----------|----------|----------|
| gcsfusecsi-node-4x7qx               | 3/3   | Running  | 0        | 4d1h     |
| gcsfusecsi-node-968kn               | 3/3   | Running  | 0        | 98m      |
| gcsfusecsi-node-k8nk5               | 3/3   | Running  | 0        | 4d       |
| gcsfusecsi-node-r9mqj               | 3/3   | Running  | 0        | 4d1h     |
| parallelstore-csi-node-cmklp        | 2/2   | Running  | 0        | 98m      |
| parallelstore-csi-node-d66dg        | 2/2   | Running  | 0        | 4d       |
| parallelstore-csi-node-jbtv7        | 2/2   | Running  | 0        | 4d       |
| parallelstore-csi-node-mnlw2        | 2/2   | Running  | 0        | 98m      |
| pdcsi-node-4tl51                    | 2/2   | Running  | 0        | 4d       |
| pdcsi-node-5h8jm                    | 2/2   | Running  | 0        | 4d       |
| pdcsi-node-5sj28                    | 2/2   | Running  | 1 (4d1h ago) | 4d1h |
| pdcsi-node-87gf7                    | 2/2   | Running  | 0        | 4d1h     |

Here is the helm value I use.
dags:
  # Where dags volume will be mounted. Works for both persistence and gitSync.
  # If not specified, dags mount path will be set to $AIRFLOW_HOME/dags
  mountPath: ~
  persistence:
    # Annotations for dags PVC
    annotations: {}
      gke-gcsfuse/volumes: "true"
    # Enable persistent volume for storing dags
    enabled: true
    # Volume size for dags
    size: 1Gi
    # If using a custom storageClass, pass name here
    storageClassName: standard-rwo #standard 
    # access mode of the persistent volume
    accessMode: ReadWriteMany #ReadWriteOnce
    ## the name of an existing PVC to use
    existingClaim: MY_EXISTING_PVC
    ## optional subpath for dag volume mount
    subPath: ""

My PV Configuration:
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  name: gcs-fuse-csi-pv
spec:
  accessModes:
  - ReadWriteMany
  capacity:
    storage: 5Gi
  storageClassName:  standard-rwo #storage-class
  mountOptions:
    - implicit-dirs
  csi:
    driver: gcsfuse.csi.storage.gke.io
    volumeHandle: my_bucket_name
    volumeAttributes:
      gcsfuseLoggingSeverity: warning
  claimRef:
    name: gcs-fuse-csi-static-pvc
    namespace: airflow

PVC Configuration:
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: gcs-fuse-csi-static-pvc
  namespace: airflow
spec:
  accessModes:
  - ReadWriteMany
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 5Gi
  storageClassName:  standard-rwo #storage-class

Questions:

How do I correctly configure the PVC and PodSpec to bind to this PV in an Airflow deployment on GKE?
Is there a specific configuration required for the Airflow Helm chart to support GCS Fuse?

Any help or suggestions would be appreciated!
